# Can I control 5 V input on a CD4051 but power the IC with 3.3 V?

Tags: analog, analog-switch

The datasheet of the CD4051 says:

- Wide Analog Input Voltage Range: ±5 V Maximum.

CD54HC and CD74HC Types

- Operation Control Voltage: 2 V to 6 V
- Switch Voltage: 0 V to 10 V

In my circuit I power (VCC) the IC with 3.3 V.
I have a variable analog voltage with a maximum of 5 V on analog pins (mux-an-in-*).

If I increase the voltage to over 4 V the chip conducts the voltage without being activated and also conducts a different voltage than the input voltage.
It actually has unexpected behavior.

Could it be because the chip can't be powered by VCC with a lower voltage than it drives on its analog pins?

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all but a few special cases, the inputs to an IC cannot go outside of the power rails by more than a few tens of mV, and it's typical to see chips specified to have inputs limited to exactly the power rails or less.

(Some chips -- **not** the CD4xxx line -- are designed to take a certain power rail but tolerate inputs at higher voltage.  Most typically a chip may run off of 3.3V, but tolerate 5V.  If so, **this fact will be featured in the product description**.  Because usually you don't need it, but when you do, you *really* do, and the feature will sell chips.)

This is because most chips have ESD protection on their inputs that's implemented with diodes to VSS and VDD, or their inputs just have implicit diodes to VSS and VDD.  In some cases (apparently in your case) putting too high a voltage on a pin means that the diode that conducts lets carriers spill out where they shouldn't, and interferes with the operation of the whole chip.

So *if* you are powering your CD5051 from +5V, *then* you can give it a +5V input and it will work properly.  But not if you're powering it from 3.3V.

You need to power the chip from 5V, or limit the input voltage to VDD.

Answer (score 3):

No. That violates the Vin > Vdd spec. and causes latchup failure.

But you could add series > 10k and Schottky diode or 3V Zener or 470 R and white LED at 3.1V. But depends on speed and load capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

This type of switch, and most switches that I know of, require that all inputs stay within the power supply range.

There are analogue switches with internal level translators that take a low voltage logic supply and a high voltage analogue supply, that allow you to use 3.3 V logic on the logic control inputs to the chip, and still switch a much higher analogue voltage. As the power supply requirement is often miniscule, this can often be provided with a flea-powered charge pump if you only have the low voltage logic power supply available.

I seem to vaguely remember that there might be some companies who produce a switch chip with internal charge pumps (just add external capacitors) that produce internal higher rails to allow higher voltage switching than the supply. If I'm right, and if you could get hold of them, they would be expensive. Stick with providing a high enough supply voltage externally.

In your particular case, the IC is rated to be powered by a high enough voltage to handle your inputs. If your 3.3 V supply was delivered through a schottky diode, the protection diode conduction in the chip (or better still an external schottky diode) would lift the VCC high enough from the input signal itself to power chip. The resulting VCC might be high enough to have the chip work properly.